# Как выбрать платформу или тулчейн при сборке в cmake?

Tags: c++, linux, c, cmake, сборка

Необходимо собрать библиотеку fmt под linux arm на x86ой машине c ubuntu 20.04 (использую кросс-компиляцию). Какие флаги необходимо передать в cmake? На машине стоит тулчейн `arm-linux-gnueabihf`. Всё что я нашёл, это флаг `-A`, но какой параметр туда передать, чтобы сборка началась при помощи нужного тулчейна, я не знаю.

Хочу обратить внимание что речь идёт не про скрипт cmake а про вызов команды cmake на исходный код библиотеки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается где то так. Вначале нужно сделать (или раздобить) файл cmake для тулчейна. В [документации есть пример](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html). Вы глядит он где то так

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /home/devel/rasp-pi-rootfs)
set(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX /home/devel/stage)

set(tools /home/devel/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

как по мне, то переменные там все очевидные. Можно добавить своих параметром по вкусу.

Теперь, когда такой файл есть, можно запускать вот так

```
cmake /path/to/cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/toolchain/tools.cmake
```

и дальше как обычно.

Ещё почитать - https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/CrossCompiling

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А нет механизма просто сделать это через флаги, как, например, в b2? `/b2 address-model=32 architecture=arm toolset=gcc-arm target-os=linux`. Мне тяжело поверить, что в такой навороченной системе как cmake не предусмотрели такой возможности.

Comment: та по моему нормальный способ - один раз написали и поехали. А хочется именно простоты - используйте cmake - там как раз можно вся прописать ручками